# How to use javascript functions written in external file, in react-native application?

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, mathjax, wiris

I am working on a project for Math-Tuition(React-native mobile app), and using `wiris` for setting up questions and answers. wiris sends those questions in MathML, I am converting MathML(equations, graphs etc) into JSX by using npm package `react-native-mathjax`.

My web team has developed same on web in vue.js, wiris also gives input felids variables to write answers, I need to do some middle calculation/re-format on those variables by using some javascript functions, Those functions are written in a external file in javascript and same file web developer(vue.js) using.

I was trying to inject js code in webview but  unable to import that js functions file in react-native, Can someone suggest me better. Thanks in advance :)
I am sharing code of import js file. Code is even not giviing error if i write wrong path of external js file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class sampleReactApp extends Component {
render() {
let HTML = `<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="./quizzes.js"></script> </head> <body> <div id="workbookControl"></div> <div id="tableeditor" style="font-size : 50px;">I am written inside source HTML</div> <div id="msg" onclick="javascript:alert('Hi')" style="font-size : 50px;" >notify alert</div> </body> </html>`;
let jsCode = `alert("Js");`;

```
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <WebView ref={ref => { this.webview = ref; }}
                source={{ html: HTML }}
                injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
                javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
            >
            </WebView>
        </View>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show your code for injecting js into the webview? In case there was something wrong there

Comment: Thanks @Harrison, for your response :)
I ahve edited question please check code there. You can copy paste and check. Also that alert in jsCode not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the official `WebView` documentation, your HTML needs to be a string, enclosed in quotation marks. Also, below, for injected javascript code to work you need to pass the `onMessage` prop (see here: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1260). So simply passing an empty function will fix it. Also according to the offical docs (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/1260), it asks you to include `true;` at the end to prevent silent failures. Finally, loading a static html requires you setting the `originWhitelist` prop in `WebView` to `originWhitelist={['']}` (https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#source)

```
import React from 'react'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'

export default class sampleReactApp extends React.Component {
    render () {
        var HTML = `<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="./quizzes.js"></script> </head> <body> <div id="workbookControl"></div> <div id="tableeditor" style="font-size : 50px;">I am written inside source HTML</div> <div id="msg" onclick="javascript:alert('Hi')" style="font-size : 50px;" >notify alert</div> </body> </html>`
        var jsCode = `alert('hello world'); true;`
        return (
            <WebView
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                source={{ html: HTML }}
                injectedJavaScript={jsCode}
                onMessage={() => {}}
                javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, onMessage worked well , But still I am waiting for an answer, How can i call function written on external js file.
example this function how can call :=> 
function hello(ddd) {
 alert("heiii")
        return "Hello";
} 
Or do I need to change method definition format ?

Comment: Is there any way I can share you js file having all functions ? So that you can suggest me a way of import and export inside javascript. Because the same file is being used in  web app.

Comment: @Priyanka Sadh simply do `(function hello(ddd) { alert("heiii"); return "Hello"; })(); true;`

Comment: This is for external js file, And what should I do in web-view code, to run that function hello(). Right now whatever I am trying is not getting called.

Comment: @Priyanka Sadh if you want to run `hello()` from react, you can simply create a `ref` to the `WebView` and using that `ref`, do `.injectJavaScript()`. Ex. `WebViewRef.injectJavaScript(`function(){ alert('Hello World!') }; true;`)`

Comment: yes thats correct but not able to call external file function in web-view <html> <script> src="file-name" </script> </html>